# should be factors with the same levels, error and reference

Tags: r, error-handling, knn, confusion-matrix

I have this code (below) and need to use CARET and split the data set in 40% of all data in the dataset should be in trainset, the rest in testset; the payment variable should be distributed equally across the split but the code of the confusionmatrixline gives an error which says:

"Error: data and reference should be factors with the same levels."

EDIT: the payment variable is a binominal variable so 0 (no) and 1 (yes). gdp are just numbers

Sample dataset: (don't now how to make a table here yet)

```
payment    gdp 

0          838493

1         9303032

0          72738 

1        38300022

1         283283
```

How to fix this??

My code:

```
 `index <- createDataPartition(y = dataset$payment, p = 0.40, list = F)
 trainset <- dataset[index, ]
 testset <- dataset[-index, ]

payment_knn <- train(payment ~ gdp, method = "knn", data = trainset, 
trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 5))
predicted_outcomes <- predict(payment_knn, testset)
conMX_pay <- confusionMatrix(predicted_outcomes, testset$payment) 
conMX_pay `
```

Comment: First don't use `matrix` as a variable name. Second, please provide sample data using `dput(head(dataset,20))`.

Comment: @NelsonGon dont know how to make it a proper table yet..

Comment: The sample data you provide is not enough. You can edit using CTRL+K to format your data and/or code. Just add the output of the code in my earlier comment. It should start with `structure(bla bla bla)`

Comment: It appears to be a binary classification problem. Is payment set as a factor?

Comment: You need to make sure train and test data are essentially the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is purely for illustration purposes. Make sure test data is the same as train data.

```
df<-df %>% 
  mutate(payment=as.factor(payment),gdp=as.numeric(gdp))
metric<-"Accuracy"
control<-trainControl(method="cv",number = 10)
train_set<-createDataPartition(df$payment,p=0.8,list=F)
valid_me<-df[-train_set,]
train_me<-df[train_set,]
#Training
  set.seed(233)       

fit.knn<-train(payment~.,method="knn",data=train_me,metric=metric,trControl=control)
    validated<-predict(fit.knn,valid_me)
    confusionMatrix(validated,valid_me$payment)
```

This works fine given the data in your question. Warnings because the data set is too small. Purely for illustration.
Data Used:

```
payment      gdp
1       0   838493
2       1  9303032
3       0    72738
4       1 38300022
5       1   283283
```

Cheers!

Comment: This works for me! Thanks! I only wonder what the metric <- "Accuracy" does. Can you explain it? :)

Comment: Hi, glad it worked.Please accept this answer if it works. The metric is just one of several metrics. You can learn more about metrics like RMSE,MAE,etc. It's too broad for a single comment unfortunately.